# Print nth pipeline command in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, error-handling

In `bash`, the `PIPESTATUS` array holds the return values of commands in a pipeline.

Suppose that in the pipeline `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`, the second command returns an error. Checking `PIPESTATUS` gives the index of the failed command, but how might one print the name of the command itself, `cmd2`?

It would be nice to show the arguments to `cmd2` as well, but I will accept an answer that only prints the command name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# put commands in an array, e.g.: cat /etc/passwd | grep 1555 | grep sh
cmd=("cat /etc/passwd" "grep 1555" "grep sh")

# execute commands
eval "${cmd[0]}" | eval "${cmd[1]}" | eval "${cmd[2]}"

# save PIPESTATUS
save=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")

# print returncode and failed command
for ((i=0;i<${#save[@]};i++)); do
  [[ ${save[$i]} -ne 0 ]] && echo "${save[$i]}: ${cmd[$i]}"
done

unset save cmd
```

Output (e.g.):

```
1: grep 1555
1: grep sh
```

Comment: It's a shame there isn't a more elegant way, but this does do the job.